# Why is a square matrix with $n-1$ eigenvalues not diagonizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am told that there exists a square matrix $A$, of size $n \times  n$.

I am given the characteristic polynomial to be $(x-2)(x-2)(x+4)(x-4)$.

Since the highest degree is $4$, I assume that $A$ must be of size $4 \times 4$. Since the characteristic polynomial only has $3$ distinct roots (eigenvalues), I can see that it is not diagonizable. But why does not having n distinct roots make it not diagonizable?

Comment: It may still be diagonalisable. For example, the diagonal matrix with diagonal $(2, 2, -4, 4)$ has that characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -4\end{bmatrix}$$

is diagonalizable.

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -4\end{bmatrix}$$

is not.

For the matrix to be diagonalizable, check that for each eigenvalue, the geometric multiplicity is equal to tbe algebraic multiplicity.

Having distinct eigenvalues implies that a matrix is diagonalizable but the converse is not true.

Answer (score 1):

You are right saying that the degree of the characteristic polynomial is equal to the dimension of the matrix. However, they are plenty of diagonalizable matrices with non-distinct eigenvalues, *e.g.* any homothety. Regarding your precise case, a diagonal matrix with entries $2,2,-4,4$ has the given characteristic polynomial and is diagonalizable.

If your point is that there exists a non-diagonalizable matrix with characteristic polynomial $$(x-2)^2(x-4)(x+4)$$
then this is certainly true taking:
$$\begin{pmatrix}2&1&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&4&0\\0&0&0&-4\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: An n by n matrix is "diagonalizable" if and only if there are n independent eigen**vectors**.  The number of distinct eigen**values** is irrelevant.

Comment: So as long as there are 4 independent eigenvalues, it doesn't matter if they are distinct? How do I show that they are independent just given the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: What does it mean for eigenvalues to be independent? The point is that eigenvectors associated with distinct eigenvalues are independent. Therefore, if all the eigenvalues of a matrix are distinct, it is diagonalizable. All the answerers are trying to point out that that the pieces of information you provided are insufficient to conclude.

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding what I wrote.  In makes no sense to talk about eigenvalues, which are **numbers** being "independent".  A 4 by 4 matrix is diagonalizable if and only if there are 4 independent eigen[b]vectors[/b].  And you [b]can't[/b] "that they are independent just given the characteristic polynomial".  It is possible to have two matrices with exactly the same characteristic polynomial but having different eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

It's false: the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\
0&0&4&0\\
0&0&0&-4\end{bmatrix}$$
has the same characteristic polynomial and is diagonal. So if your matrix is not diagonalisabl, there must be someting else.

What is true is that a matrix with *simple* eigenvalues *is* diagonalisable.. Hence, if it's not, it must have *multiple* eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix can have 3 distinct and be diagonalizable, take as example the matrix that ha value $(2,2,4,-4)$ in the diagonal, and $0$ otherwise.

What happens is that to a matrix be diagonalizable, it deppend not of the characterisct polynomial, but actually of it's minimal polynomial, a matrix will not be diagonalizable if and only if all roots of the minimal polynomial are distinct.

If you want to know more about that you should look for Jordan Canonical Form of a matrix.